# Gnuplot: Black and White contour plot

Tags: latex, gnuplot, contour

I have the following gnuplot plot embedded in my Latex document:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions={color size 14.5cm, 9cm}]
set view map
unset surface

unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics

set contour base
set cntrparam levels discrete 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512
set isosamples 100

splot y**2 + 0.1*x**2 notitle
\end{gnuplot}
```

The plot is alright. All I want to achive is that the contour lines all have the same style, i.e. line type and the same colour, black if possible.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the latex terminal, but you could try:

```
splot y**2 + 0.1*x**2 notitle lc rgb "#000000"
```

http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/contours.html  (see the section where they draw all the contours in the same color -- It's the last example on that page)

**EDIT**

It looks like the coloring of the contours is controlled by `{un}set clabel`.  So if you just add `unset clabel` to your script, then the contours should probably show up black (with the `lc rgb "#000000"` that I had above.  Note that `unset clabel` implies `unset key`.  To achieve this with the ability to add a key is a little more tricky...

*in case you ever need to keep the labels...*

You'll likely need to `set term push` to save the current terminal.  `set term unknown` to make the output go nowhere.  `set table "junk.dat"` and then issue your plot commmand as normal.  This will write the contours to a file "junk.dat" which can then be splotted with lines after a `set term pop` to restore the old terminal settings (you'll probably need some variant of `title columnhead` and maybe an index/every as well to get the labels to appear correctly...) -- I'm not actually sure if the `set term push/pop` commands are necessary in this case.  Anyway, plotting things to tables with gnuplot is something that I've done a number of times for a number of different applications.  It's a great tool to keep in mind.

Comment: Hm, sounds like what I want. But unfortunaly it doesnt work by simply adding it to my code. The example from the site does work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Haatschii -- It looks like the coloring of the contours is determined by `clabel` if it is set (`help clabel`).  If you unset it, the colors will be determined by your plot command.  Unfortunately, `unset clabel` (I think) implies `unset key` which is fine for your example...